# Attaching an intent to a list item restored from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have an activity that lets the user load some data when they press a button. That data is passed to a list and each list item has different data stored in it. When they click on the list item it launches an intent which passes them to a new class.

But when I store the first value returned from pressing this button, i.e. using the onStop() and using SharedPreferences, and click on it I get an error. I think it may be something to do with the intent - the list item just isn't attaching to it. Here is part of the code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems );
    setListAdapter( adapter );

    list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemClickListener( this );

    if( settings.contains( "ARRAY_LIST_VALUE_0" ) )
    {
        listItems.add( 0, settings.getString( "ARRAY_LIST_VALUE_0",tempStore ) );   
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    reload = (Button)findViewById( R.id.reloadTen );
    reload.setOnClickListener( this );

    // Original onItemClicked was in here
    list.setTextFilterEnabled( true );  
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listItem, int position, long arg3) 
{
    // Start an activity based on what list view item is pressed
    Intent intent = new Intent( newSightings.this, newCompass.class );

    // Pass the data we retrieved to the next activity
    intent.putExtra( "info",data[position]  );
    startActivity( intent );
}

@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME,0 );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    if( usrPrssdBtn )
    {   
            // Store the latitude and longitude values and then reload them if known
            editor.putString( "LAT",myNewLat );
            editor.putString( "LONG",myNewLon );

            // Place first element of array list in storage
            if( adapter.getCount() > 0 )
            {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Leaving Activity, Adapter Size: "+ adapter.getCount()+"\nStoring: "+listItems.get( 0 ).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                tempStore = listItems.get( 0 ).toString();

                editor.putString( "ARRAY_LIST_VALUE_0",tempStore );
                editor.putString( "DATA",data[arryTrckr] );  
            }
    }
    editor.commit();

}
```

So - when I run the activity and then press back, then go back to the activity the stored list item is there. Problem is when I click it it crashes the app. What's the problem? I get a NullPointerException at this line:

```
intent.putExtra( "info",data[position] );
```

Comment: data is an array that holds the values of the results from the web parsing and stores them to be passed onto the next activity

Comment: replace data[arryTrckr] with listitems[arryTrckr] in onStop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adapter = new ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems );

in the above line you are using listitems array to sidplay the data.
where as onItemclick event you are using

data[position] to fetch the data according to me when you are displaying data from listitems array the you must use listitems[position] to fetch the data

Comment: Can you elaborate you are a little hard to understand

Comment: replace data[position] with listitems[position] and try

Comment: Hello - that worked well. Thanks mate :D Tell me if I am correct here - originally when trying to move back from activity B -> activity A I was trying to reference something that wasn't there - i.e. the null pointer exception. But when changing the data to listItems as so: listItems.get( position ) this references something which as been saved therefore it works?

Comment: i didnt get you can you elaborate

Comment: When returning from one activity to another that previous data is saved and therefore can be recalled

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is that your Intent is null when you go from Activity A -> Activity B -> back to Activity A -> Activity B again?

I think that the first time you launched your Intent from A -> B, the Intent was passed on, and then you onResume activity A when you go back from B.  If your Intent isn't reinitialized (`new Intent(...)`), then the reference you're holding to it in Activity A will be invalid.

At least, that's the best I can do without more context. :)

I have to ask a broader question:  If you have an Activity whose purpose it is to modify your settings, why not use a PreferenceActivity?

Comment: I looked at PreferenceActivity and it doesn't seem right to use it as it isn't a preference set by the user. It's actually just keeping the results of, basically, a query - so wouldn't PreferenceActivity be incorrect on that part?

Comment: It seems curious to store a query result in SharedPreferences.  Is this permanent data or transient data?  If it's something more transient (doesn't need to be persisted across application sessions) you might consider using startActivityForResult in Activity A and returning information in the resulting intent from Activity B.

Comment: I suppose it would be more permanent data, you know when the app is closed it re-displays this data...that old chestnut :P